# How to assemble a Namespace in a WPF project

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm, namespaces

I'm learning WPF and trying to reproduce this [DataTemplate example](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/Data%20Binding/DataTemplatingIntro) related to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview), writing the code-behind in VB (in the example is in C#). The first issue I'm facing is that I don't know how to assemble a Namespace created in the MainWindow.xaml.vb file. I read a lot of questions related here but I haven't been able to find a solution. I recompile the project and it run properly but the error is still there. I also read that could be a VS bug related with the architecture setting of the app (x64 x86).

MainWindow.xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="DataTemplatingIntro.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SDKSample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

MainWindow.xaml.vb file:

```
Imports System.Windows

Namespace DataTemplatingIntro
Public Class MainWindow
    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

*Severity Code Description Project File Line Status deleted
Error XLS0414 The type 'DataTemplatingIntro.MainWindow' was not found. Verify that a reference to an assembly is not missing and that all referenced assemblies have been compiled. SDKSample MainWindow.xaml*

I tried to add the name of the assembly:

```
xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:DataTemplatingIntro;assembly=MyLibAssembly
```

I tried to add as local too:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SDKSample:DataTemplatingIntro"
```

But nothing works. How can I solve this annoying VS issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try with just `x:Class="MainWindow"`? I tried a sample project and namespace was not needed

Comment: @sim1 Yes, that works and is as it comes by default. But I was looking to add a namespace to understand the concept and be able to use it in future projects so that all the code is better organized.

Comment: namespace separator is dot - `SDKSample.DataTemplatingIntro`, not colon `SDKSample:DataTemplatingIntro`

Comment: @ASh Yes, you are right. I tried `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SDKSample.DataTemplatingIntro"` but it didn't work too. I don't know what I am missing here.

Comment: On some of the WPF applications used separate namespaces for the view and view models. After adding the namespaces had to do a full rebuild before Visual Studio would find the reference and stop complaining.

Comment: @RyanRoos Did you have this issue too?

Comment: I don't think you can use a relative namespace in `x:Class`.  If your namespace (including whatever is added in the project settings) is `SDKSample.DataTemplatingIntro`, then that needs to be what you use in `x:Class`.  Alternatively, if you use an `xmlns` directive to make a reference in xaml e.g. `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SDKSample.DataTemplatingIntro` then you would use `x:Class="local:MyWindow"`.